how can i use Motion library in dartpad.dev?
This is the code i am working on in dartpad.dev and its not working because Motion library is not getting imported. How can i fix it?
I want to use the animation and for that i need Motion library to work and get imported in dartpad
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:motion/motion.dart'; // **issues here**



DartPad is meant to be a quick and easy way for people to try Dart and to play around with it. It is not meant to be full development environment. If you need to do things that DartPad is incapable of, don't use DartPad. Install the Dart (or Flutter) SDK yourself.

DartPad supports a limited set of packages, which you can find here. Unfortunately, the motion package is not one of them.
If you need to use the motion package for animations, it's best to install the Flutter SDK and work locally. DartPad doesn’t allow users to add custom packages, as explained by the DartPad team here:

Adding support for new packages requires a lot of work, and in some cases, it simply won't be possible. For example, the google_mobile_ads plugin is unlikely ever to be available in DartPad. However, updating the allowed list of packages with new libraries, and occasionally removing old ones, is definitely part of the plan going forward.

